# unable to load fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Sherlock Fragments library to sliding menu.my problem is i unable to load fragment when i click button in activity. I am getting java.lang.classcastException
to android.app.activity.

I have imported:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

but still I am getting error.

code for mainActivity.

```
public class AmecmainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      actionnetwork=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ActionNetwork);
      actionnetwork.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent action=new Intent(v.getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                Fragment2.class);
        startActivity(action);  

        }
    });
```

and code in fragment2

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment{

    Fragment fragment;
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionnetworklogin, container, false);
    Button login = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              });
    } 
return view;
```

can any one help me

framelayout xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

          <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

onclick method :

```
  actionnetwork=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ActionNetwork);
  actionnetwork.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          Fragment fragment = new Fragment2();
          FragmentManager fm =getSupportFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
          transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); 
          transaction.commit(); 
    }
});



  fragment2 xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Second Fragment"
    android:textSize="15pt" />

    </RelativeLayout>



mainactivity:

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >

         <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ActionNetwork"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

code for pervious fragment

```
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case R.id.menuIcon:
         toggle();
         break; 
     case android.R.id.home:

         getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                            }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

fragment2.class file

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    Button clicked=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.clickedmove);
    clicked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Fragment fragment = new Fragment2();
              FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();
              FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
              transaction.addToBackStack(null);
              transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment); 
              transaction.commit(); 
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

Comment: Have you try to extend SherlockFragment And SherlockFragmentActivity instead Fragment and FragmentActivity?

Comment: no i haven't extended

Comment: so try it, but i'n not sure that will help :)

Comment: @user3069112 post the stacktrace

Comment: @user3069112 Fragment is not a Activity. You need a container and need to add the fragment to the container

Comment: how can i add container pls tell me i am new to fragments

Comment: @user3069112 check my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fragment2` is a fragment not a Activity. Fragment is hosted by a Activity. The below is wrong

```
 Intent action=new Intent(v.getContext().getApplicationContext(),Fragment2.class);
 startActivity(action);
```

You are missing `setContentView` for the `Activity`.

```
public class AmecmainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // missing
```

Then

You need a Container in activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout 
      android:id="@+id/fragment_container" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />
```

Then in `onClick`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Edit:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: every time when i want go to next fragment should i write frame layout

Comment: @user3069112 there is an example @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html. even in the sdk samples you will find examples related.

Comment: ok thanks should i write the all the views inside the frame layout or its not required when i write all the views inside the frame layout all the elements get disturbed any suggestion

Comment: @user3069112 you are getting confused. FrameLayout is meant to host the fragment. So what you are doing is wrong. In `activity_main.xml`. Have the framelayout where you want. have the image button where you want not as a child of framelayout. Specify the width and heights. Now in java code add the fragment to the container ie framelayout. FOr framgent layout you have a different layout xml which is inflated in onCreateView of fragment

Comment: i did same what you have said but it is giving error i have declared framelayout in different xml file and added id of container but it is giving me error

Comment: 12-27 05:24:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2572): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f040091 (com.arivoli.amec:id/fragment_container) for fragment Fragment2{b3de3dc8 #0 id=0x7f040091}

Comment: @user3069112 what is the error specify and post updated code along with xml

Comment: @user3069112 where is imagebutton in your layout. which layout xml is set to the activity. i said full code

Comment: sorry i have uploaded

Comment: i have included all the layouts and java files also

Comment: should framelayout be as parent layout or  child layout

Comment: 12-27 05:51:08.322: E/AndroidRuntime(2626): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f040052 (com.arivoli.amec:id/fragment_container) for fragment Fragment2{b3de2e90 #0 id=0x7f040052}
12-27 05:51:08.322: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
12-27 05:51:08.322: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)

Comment: @user3069112 you never understood my previous comments. pls check the edit of my post. if you have a error should post in your question not in comment section

Comment: sorry sorry I am placing the framelayout in second fragment xml

Comment: @user3069112 that is also wrong. activity hosts fragment you need framelayout in actiivty

Comment: THanks boss your really great it works finally but i am getting the only half the screen

Comment: @user3069112 it is not half screen it is the way you designed xml and it has nothing to do with the code above. read the docs and learn

Comment: what should i do if i want get full screen

Comment: @user3069112 design you layout xml in the way you want.

Comment: ok ok one more issue if want to previous fragments.I have written code  above can you please tell me why it is not functioning

Comment: @user3069112 can you pls post a new question coz this is leading to a discussion. New problem new post pls

Comment: @user3069112 it will come up in the new question section on android tag. If you have a issue regarding how this site functions meta.stackoverflow.com. ask a question on meta. the moderators will answer.

Comment: i have posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800014/how-to-move-to-previous-fragment-on-button-click

Comment: your are not replying to me u said me to post a new question .i have given you link also

Comment: @user3069112 you should have patience first. Pls get to know how the site works first. By the way what have you done to resolve your issue other than saying it does not work or i have this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't call Fragment Like this:

You have to use this:

```
 void addfragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addBacktoStack, int transition) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(transition);
    if (addBacktoStack)
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

}
```

And call this method like this:

```
 addfragment(new Fragment2(contextHere),true,FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
```

Comment: `new Fragment2(contextHere)`. I believe fragment must have a no arg constructor

Comment: But when the Fragment is created then the Context of that particular class will be pass there as a arg. And I have used many times and working well.

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html. Quoting "Default constructor. Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments()."

Comment: Fragment fragment = new Fragment2();
     FragmentManager fm =getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction transaction =  fm.beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment); 
     transaction.commit();

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f04008f (com.arivoli.amec:id/content_frame) for fragment Fragment2{b3cf5c80 #0 id=0x7f04008f}

Comment: Check that there is id of content_frame in xml file??

Comment: there is no context_frame in second xml i just used relative layout and a text view

Comment: but the view which you inflated for fragment you have to give id for that

Comment: can i give the layout id??

Comment: The View which you want to add as a Fragment , you have to give id to that

Comment: want to add second layout as fragment

Comment: Ok..So declare id for that in xml and use it

Comment: for more info see http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/07/simple-fragment-example-in-android.html  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm     http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example

Answer (score 1):

In the activity, the fragment can be loaded using;

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();        
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.container_main, new MyFragment())
               .commit();
```

where **MyFragment** is as;

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_trending, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and a simple Fragment xml, would look like:

```
<RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="in.stocksphere.stocksphere.MyFragment$PlaceholderFragment" >

            <TextView android:text="@string/ta_user"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```